# Still able to login using removed logins

Tags: support, login, user-accounts

I deleted two of my logins on Stack Overflow, so that I'm using a single login. In the "my logins" area I see that the logins are deleted, even after logging out and back in again. However, it's still letting me login with my old logins.

Why does this do this? Is there a way to permanently erase old logins?

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I'm reasonably sure happened. Somehow you ended up with four accounts. Two of those you merged yourself through the contact form, and two more merges happened automatically in the process of your login attempts.

Let's say you have three email addresses on your account after account merge went through. Let's call them E, R, and S.

Email address E was associated with two types of credentials - Yahoo and an email/password combo (a.k.a. StackId). You removed it from your logins about 3 hours ago, *but* that only removed the StackId credential, not Yahoo, so the email address was still associated with your logins. Then it looks like you logged in on stackexchange.com, which triggered the first of the automated merges - which went by the email credential and find your main account. The merge then put the StackId credential back since that's what merges do.

Then the same thing more or less happened again - you removed credential E, that removed the StackId but not Yahoo, there was another login event and another merge.

Then you removed E again and this time the Yahoo credential is gone. So now you're down to two StackId credentials, one linked to email E and the other to email S.

If you remove E again, it should be gone from your account for good. *However*, our email/password credentials are [OpenIDs under the hood](https://openid.stackexchange.com). If you want to have it deleted permanently, please [contact our support team](/contact).